# Python.NET - Name must not be empty

Tags: c#, python, pip, conda, python.net

I'm embedding some Python code in C#/.NET and it breaks on this line in Python.NET during import:

```
public ModuleObject(string name): base() {

if (name==String.Empty)
{
   throw new ArgumentException("Name must not be empty!")
}
```

...

How is it possible that some imported Python module is empty string???

So far this is not reproducible on other machine.

I'm using this branch (locally compiled):

https://github.com/renshawbay/pythonnet

Comment: Need more context, what method is calling the method you have referenced? What is the content of the variable `name`? When you say 'import', what are you actually doing?

Comment: That code is not complete so it shouldn't even compile (you're missing a closing brace).  It appears to be a class constructor.  How are you calling this constructor?

Comment: this is just a code snap where python.net breaks, looks like seaborn was not installed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may be caused by relative imports. It appears that this has been patched. For me a fix involved upgrading from `pythonnet-2.1.0` to `pythonnet-2.2.2`

```
pip install pythonnet --upgrade
```

## References

- https://github.com/matthid/pythonnet/commit/28239416e4d30edc0ddd24e77e4181b1c4646c3b
- https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/pull/182#issuecomment-222008972

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn 0.5.1 is not correctly installed/uninstalled using Anaconda on Windows 7, 64bit, Python 2.7.

'conda remove seaborn' leaves some seaborn files in site-packages.

---

EDIT

I just realised why this happened - another process blocked complete uninstallation of seaborn package. this is both for conda and pip. so probably has nothing to do with seaborn or conda.

Comment: Did you install seaborn with conda or with pip?

Comment: initially yes, after finding this problem I tried with pip. pip cleans up itself, but neither conda nor pip can clean up seaborn installed by conda.

Comment: I just realised why this happened - another process blocked complete uninstallation of seaborn package. this is both for conda and pip. so probably has nothing to do with seaborn or conda.